# AWS CodePipeline with Github Actions 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, aws-codepipeline

Recently (Oct 2020) AWS started using GitHub Actions v2 and now when I select the GitHub private repository in my code I get this error:

`Invalid input: when using CodePipeline both sourceType, and artifactType must be set to: CODEPIPELINE`

Default "Source provider" is selected as "AWS CodePipeline but when I change it to GitHub it throws the above error.

Comment: How you solved this issue ?

Comment: Hi, I'm don't remember the exact steps but it started working after a week for me. My guess is that it was a bug on AWS side and they fixed it.